# Vector derivative partial to w

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

What's the derivative of E (below equation) partial to **w**: ( consider that w is vector)
[image]

Comment: Just compute the derivative with respect to each component $w_j$. This will give you a vector which is your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $k \in \{0,1,\ldots,M\}$:

$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial w_k} = \sum_{n=1}^N x_n^k\, x_n^i = 0$$